# how set text direction in android

Tags: android

I have a textview and I set farsi/arabic text in it and set gravity as right but it in tablets display text in left .and if set gravity left display it right.what I do until it work as true?

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            >
<TextView android:layout_width="fill_parent"
          android:layout_height="wrap_content"
          android:id="@+id/manage_account_id_textview"
          android:text="فارسي"
          android:gravity="right"
          />
</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

do like this

```
<LinearLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

    <RelativeLayout android:layout_width="fill_parent"
                  android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                >

    <TextView android:layout_width="wrap_content"
              android:layout_height="wrap_content"
              android:id="@+id/manage_account_id_textview"
              android:text="فارسي"
              android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
              />
    </RelativeLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Answer (score 0):

Try using

```
 manage_account_id_textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_RTL);
```

or

```
 manage_account_id_textview.setTextDirection(View.TEXT_DIRECTION_ANY_RTL);
```